# Navbar Assigning navbar-expand-md Automatically

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-5, plotly-dash

I am trying to style my navbar with BS5 installed, nowhere do I have navbar-expand-md as a className, instead, I assign a navbar-expand-custom myself.

```
navbar = _dbc.Navbar(
        
        [
            _dbc.Col(
               # Logo Contents
            ),
              
            _dbc.Col(
              # Title Contents
            ),
            
            _dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler", n_clicks=0),
            
            _dbc.Collapse(
                children=[right_elems],
                id="navbar-collapse",
                is_open=False,
                navbar=True
            ),
        ],
        className="navbar-expand-custom",
        id="navbar-id",
        style=style,
        **{**navbardefaults, **navbarkwargs},
    )
```

whenever I go to inspect the elements, there seems to be navbar-expand-md assigned as a className, which is overriding what I need in terms of styling.

I tried using JS to get the navbar-id and removing the className but I am wondering if there is any reason why it is assigning it by default with no mention of it in my code? Is there any way to override it? The logic doesn't even make sense because even with both classnames present, the navbar-expand-custom comes after the navbar-expand-md in the bs5.css file.

Answer (score 0):

`navbar-expand-*` is applied by default [as per documentation](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/):

> **expand** (boolean | string; default 'md'): Specify breakpoint at which
> to expand the menu bar. Options are: 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', or 'xl'.
> Below this breakpoint the navbar will collapse and navitems will be
> placed in a togglable collapse element.

So try setting `expand=False` on `dbc.Navbar`.

If that fails, add the class `navbar-expand` on `dbc.Navbar` (`class_name="navbar-expand"`). [From the bootstrap documentation:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)

> For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the
> navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand
> class.

Also note the likely reason why your CSS is not overriding the `navbar-expand-md` class is because its CSS rules are all inside `@media` queries, at Bootstrap's medium breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex!important;
    flex-basis: auto;
}
```